# Synonym proposal: [.procmailrc] -> [procmail]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

There are currently two unrelated Procmail-related tags: [procmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procmail) and [.procmailrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.procmailrc).  I would like to propose that the latter be made a synonym of the former on Stack Overflow.

The file `$HOME/.procmailrc` file is the default location for user-created Procmail recipes.  In the scope of programming Procmail, I find it hard to imagine a situation where a problem would be specific to `.procmailrc` while conversely I find it hard to imagine a [procmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procmail) problem which would not at least tangentially also involve `.procmailrc`.

(You can put system-wide rules in `/etc/procmailrc` which is not a `.procmailrc` file, since it uses a slightly different file name, but the syntax is the same.)

There are currently [111 `procmail` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procmail) and [27 `.procmailrc` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.procmailrc) though most of these (20 questions) are a also tagged [procmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procmail).

Comment: Just retag those questions...

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for the feedback.  I have now emptied the [tag:.procmailrc] tag, replacing it with [tag:procmail] on those questions which did not already have it. [My recent revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee?tab=activity&sort=revisions) from just now should reveal what I did.

Comment: This is now [tag:status-completed] but the synonym doesn't exist.  I tried to propose it just now but I get an error message that "the tag needs to exist in the system".  Though perhaps we are just as well off without this synonym.